# django user table - is it better to create custom one?

Tags: django

I saw someone wrote a user account/authentication (in github).

The reason he wrote it, he said, is that he does not like normal users and admin user share a table. (He did not use User model)

I am new in python django. Is it better to do it his way or is this not really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really necessary, the Django provided authentication app is really good, even more, from Django 1.5 on you can provide your own user model, before it was necessary to create an additional model (profile), but now you can just replace the model with one of your own and add any fields you need.

Comment: Then another question: I see many examples that use profile model in conjunction with User mode. Is it better just stick to a derived user model? The only benefit i can see in using 2 models instead of a single User model is that the database size may be smaller - because many people may choose not to set up a profile, hence my system may end up 1000 User records but only 500 Profile record.

Comment: @user3108063 Don't worry about "database size". Worry about the correct multiplicity and normalization for your problem domain.

Comment: Its better to override the User model and user your own, before Django 1.5 it wasn't possible to use a custom user model. The difference in DB size is negligible, the support for user profiles was left for legacy purposes. However, you must consider that some apps (for example, Django CMS) are incompatible with custom user models (support hasn't been added yet), so if you need to use any currently incompatible app you have no other choice than using a separate profile model.